# Which are the differences between WinExec and ShellExecute?

Tags: winapi

I need to execute another application and I'm wondering if there's a reason why I should use `WinExec` instead of `ShellExecute` or vice versa.

Which are differences between two methods? Is there one that should be preferred?

Comment: To execute an application use `CreateProcess`, not `ShellExecute`. And forget the `WinExec` because it's deprecated for a long time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`WinExec` is long deprecated and retained only for backwards compatibility reasons. It is used to start executables. Don't use it, due to its deprecation. As stated in the documentation:

> This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows. Applications should use the CreateProcess function.

`ShellExecute` is not deprecated, but also should not be used since it cannot report errors properly.

Use `ShellExecuteEx` to execute shell verbs.

If you wish to create a process, and you know the executable file name, use `CreateProcess`. Unless you need to execute elevated in which case you need `ShellExecuteEx` with the `runas` verb.

Comment: If you don't know the executable name, you can't use winexec. The two functions are not equivalent.

Comment: @Sertac we're just not going to call  `WinExec` at all. I've explained when to use SEE and when to use CP.

Comment: That's fine. But the question deserves the difference to be mentioned, that's what it asks.

Comment: @Sertac I've expanded the answer accordingly

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks for clarification, now it's all clear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  The most logical use of ShellExecuteEx ?