# Execute CMD commands using C++

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, command

In my project I want to execute some CMD commands. What is the syntax for doing that using C++.

Comment: Lookup for the `system()` function.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can execute Windows Command prompt commands using a C++ function called `system();`. ***For safer standards*** you are recommended to use Windows specific API'S like ***ShellExecute*** or ***ShellExecuteEx***. Here is how to run CMD command using `system()` function.

You should place the CMD command like shown below in the program source code:

```
system("CMD_COMMAND");
```

Here is a program which executes the DATE command in CMD to find the date:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    system("DATE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: system is evil, unsecure, from C - use newer approaches.
[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong
[2] http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/

Answer (score 7):

Use Windows specific APIs:

- [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

[See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx) also.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could always do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace

int main()
{
    WinExec("cmd", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

This however, automatically sets the path to the folder your file is in. Just type cd\ to return to base file.

Comment: Isn't WinExec [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30127592/1234518) and therefor not wise to use?