# How to check if a given KB is installed on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-update

Is there a way to check if a given KB is installed on Windows?  Specifically, I'd like to find out if KB2999226 is installed on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Thanks.

Comment: [Windows Update Agent API - Searching, Downloading, and Installing Specific Updates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387101(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment section of the question, you need to explore the [Windows Update Agent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387101(v=vs.85).aspx) to exactly achieve this.

To search for an update say KBDDDDDDD using cmd, you can use the following:

```
wmic qfe get hotfixid | find "KBDDDDDDD"
```

You can directly call this query in C++ with the help of system() function. Please check this post to know about how to  [Execute CMD commands using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201631/execute-cmd-commands-using-c).